# What is wrong with this PHP script to send mail using Pear Mail?

Tags: php, email, smtp, pear

I have this script:

```
require_once "Mail.php";

 $from = "Stephen <username@nvrforget.com>";//Google apps domain
 $to = "username@gmail.com";
 $subject = "Hi!";
 $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

 $host = "mail.nvrforget.com";
 $username = "username@nvrforget.com";
 $password = "password";

 $headers = array ('From' => $from,
   'To' => $to,
   'Subject' => $subject);
 $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
   array ('host' => $host,
     'auth' => true,
     'username' => $username,
     'password' => $password));

 $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

 if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
   echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
  }
```

I am coming up with this error:

```
Non-static method Mail::factory() should not be called statically
```

Any idea how to fix this? Pear Mail is installed on the server.

Comment: Looks correct.  Are you sure your Pear Mail library is being included properly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Non-static method Mail::factory() should not be called statically

This is a *non-fatal notice* coming from PHP because PEAR Mail is *prehistoric* and hasn't been updated to use the `static` keyword introduced five years ago in PHP5.

After [reviewing the documentation](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.factory.php), your call to `Mail::factory` *looks* completely correct and normal.

You failed to tell us if if the call to `send` succeeds or fails.  If it's succeeding, but the mail is never being delivered, please check the SMTP server logs.  If it's failing, what's the actual error message?  The [`Mail::send`](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.send.php) documentation includes a comprehensive list of errors.

You might want to consider using a more *modern* mail sending library, like [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).

Comment: Ah... very interesting. The send doesn't seem to succeed. I will try out swiftmailer, because I would definitely prefer to have a more modern library. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

perhaps it has to do with a missing ampersand?

I notice in documentation examples, the usage of factory looks like this:

```
// Create the mail object using the Mail::factory method
$mail_object =& Mail::factory('sendmail', $params);
```

Note the assigment using =&

Comment: -1, there is no longer any need to pass objects by reference in PHP5.  That syntax is for PHP4 only.

Answer (score -2):

prepended an @ to all pear / mail calls. sometime you may end up with  Mail::factory() should not be called statically error