# PHP 5.4 and SMTP

Tags: php, email, smtp

I'm trying to use the PEAR SMTP library with PHP 5.4 but I'm having the following issues when using it:

```
> Strict Standards: Non-static method Mail::factory() should not be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\forgot.php on line 75

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\php\pear\Mail\smtp.php on line 365

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\php\pear\Net\SMTP.php on line 450

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::raiseError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\php\pear\Net\SMTP.php on line 451

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::raiseError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\php\pear\Mail\smtp.php on line 369

Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::isError() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\php\pear\Mail\smtp.php on line 249
```

As far as I'm aware, there's no fix for this until PEAR or the creators of the PEAR scripts fix them. I'm wondering what alternative SMTP libraries people use, or just what I can do to deliver e-mail from my script via SMTP to gmail. I'm using windows, if that's of any help.

Thank you.

Comment: check out this stack overflow.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114222/what-is-wrong-with-this-php-script-to-send-mail-using-pear-mail

Comment: also check out this forum posting.  http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/255144-pear-mail-problems/

Comment: and here is a posting that contains a solution by prepending an @.  it appears there is some php4 usage this is not very nice with php5 and has not been changed.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280829/sending-mail-using-php-and-pear-on-windows

Comment: phpMailer is a better mail class than the one in PEAR. I recommend switching to that.

Answer (score 1):

please use php mailer library. this will help you to resolve any email related issue in PHP.

Following is the download link of the phpmail library
http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/downloads/list

The library is available in the zip format.

Please search for test folder after extracting the zip. this will demonstrate you how to use the library.

You can also refer the [link](http://www.web-development-blog.com/archives/send-e-mail-messages-via-smtp-with-phpmailer-and-gmail/) for using gmail for email communication

Thanks!